# how to install sbt offline or without internet

Tags: scala, sbt, offline

I want to use scala sbt in a local server, which cannot connect to the internet.

So far what I got to know is that I have to install sbt with internet.
I also tried to first install sbt in a server that can access the internet, compress all the sbt files as a zip and then send them to the server without internet. However this leads to a lot of dependency errors and it wants to download things again.

How can I install the sbt offline?

Comment: Inside the SBT console, you can put it into offline mode with `set offline := true` but that obviously only helps if you have all dependencies locally available already.

Comment: Note that having to use sbt in a server without Internet sounds weird, maybe that server should not build the project but only run it? In that case it would be better to just use **sbt-assembly** to build a single jar and copy that jar to the server, which would only need a jdk installation to run the project. You may also use **Graal** to create a single executable from your project which wouldn't need the JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would try to use some sbt wrapper like [sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras) instead of globally installed package. It tries to check sbt version, download it into cache, then run it with some better defaults.

Once you started using that to start sbt, you could copy your local sbt cache `~/.sbt`, Ivy2 cache `~/.ivy2` and/or Coursier cache ([slightly harder to find](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5120)) (if I am not mistaken since 1.3 Coursier is used out of the box, before it was Ivy) from your computer to your offline machine.

This is required because you won't be able not only to install sbt but also libraries you need to compile the project.

Comment: In my case, on windows 10, I simply copied user/.sbt/ and user/AppData/Local/Coursier from a internet connected PC which was compiling without errors. Coursier folder seems to cache all libraries.